# Check for system updates on Android devices

Tags: android, ota

I'm looking for any way to check for Android OS updates from within custom Android app.

The app should be able to get info if new version is available and, if so, show appropriate message. This should work on phones provided by many manufacturers. Is there any API method or a web service which can be queried about this?

I know this feature is carrier-depended and that's way I'm not sure if it's even possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this.  Your app is sandboxed and can't access that kind of information and there is no API from the carrier's end.

Comment: Thank you! You've dissipated my dubiousness. Just one more question: could you, please, provide more details on how sandboxing influences lack of this feature?

Comment: Because your app is put in a sandbox to prevent it from damaging the operating system and only allowed to interact with it is very specific and safe ways.  Downloading and flashing a whole new operating system could very easily go wrong and severely damage the device.

Comment: Sure thing! But what about just informing a user: "You can update your OS. To do that perform the following steps..."? I don't want to automatically update the system, just check for updates availability. I suppose it isn't possible?

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but... As far as I know there are manufacturers-dependent solutions to do this check. For example, Samsung has pre-installed app, while HTC put this feature within the system. You said Android already did this, so is there a common way to enforce this check from within the code?